# Android/Java date formatting and splitting

Tags: java, android, date, formatting, split

I have a date as string **"18.07.2013 15:31:10"** and I want it to split like

```
string DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH = "18";
string DAY_OF_WEEK = "Thursday";
string MONTH_IN_YEAR = "July";
string HOUR ="15:31";
```

How should I do that? I have seen formatting posts but no idea how to split the date.

Comment: "I have seen formatting posts" then where is formatting code?

Comment: Just create a `Calendar` object out of that string. You will get everything you want. As a suggestion, consider using `Joda Time`, that will much easier in these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("18.07.2013 15:31:10");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calenadr.setTime(date);
```

then you can use `calendar` to get the info you need.

```
int dayOfTheWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

Comment: I had used this but I just noticed I'm having error because of another issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SimpleDateFormat format  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = format.parse("18.07.2013 15:31:10");
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(date);             
   int day  = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
   int month  = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
   int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
   System.out.println("day:" + day);
   System.out.println("month :"+month);       
   System.out.println("year: "+year);
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime()));
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(cal.getTime()));
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.getTime()));
```